# setInterval not working on Cyclic.sh in a post request

Tags: node.js, server, setinterval, cyclic

I have deployed a test server on Cyclic, but when I make a request that should run a setInterval, nothing appears in the logs.

Here is the code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.send("Hello World!");
});

app.post("/test", function(req, res) {
    res.send({status: "OK"});
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log(req.body.test);
    }, 1000);
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`server listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not allowed by design in **Cyclic.sh**. When new `POST /test` request is received by the server it's going to your handler, when you call `res.send({status: "OK"});` and it finish response stream is closed. When streams is closed **Cyclic.sh** knows that request has been handled and application can be terminated/suspended as it's no longer needed.

To see that `setInterval` works correctly we need to delay calling `res.send` to see everything works until response steams is closed
Below is an example that on `/` just response without waiting and another `/test` endpoint that delays sending response by using `setTimeout`. I hope it helps you understand how it works

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log("/ ping");
    }, 1000);
    console.log("/ Hello World!");
    res.send("/ Hello World!");
});

app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
    setInterval(() => {
        console.log("/test ping");
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("/test Hello World!");
        res.send("/test Hello World!");
    }, 3100);
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`server listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```